# run an R Markdown (check.Rmd ) and an R knitr (test.Rnw ) file together

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I have the following problem; There are 2 big documents, one written in `R Markdown` (check.Rmd ) and the other in `R knitr` (test.Rnw ). In the first doc we have a code like the following:

```
\section{Organisations Test}

\textbf{Running Organisations Checks}

<<CreateOrganisations, echo=FALSE, progress=TRUE, warning=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=
source("OrganisationsTest.R")
OrganisationsTest(current_schema,server,user,pass)

@
```

and in the other as follows:

````
  2. check the downwards shock
```{r chunk_Int_Sh_p2,  echo=FALSE}
unique(param.int.shock.tab[SHOCKTYPE=="SHOCK_DOWN"&PERIODEND<21|PERIODEND==90, list( Maturity=PERIODEND, Shock_value=100*SHOCKVALUE)])
```
````

Now the question: how can I combine both so that I have just one script which runs and compile both one after each other. Just for clarification, I mean without any changes in both documents how can I have just one script which applyes to the first doc `knit PDF` to create pdf and to the other one `CompilePDF` ?

I suppose in Linux one can write a shell script but what a bout using `RStudio` in windowes?
I am really  grateful for every hint I am a little bit helpless!

**Addendum**: In principle it is as follows: we have 2 files if you would compile a knitr file you would use [image: compilePDF]  bottom in RStudio, and for a Markdown file one  may use [image: KnitPDF] bottom in RStudio, BUT we want to put both together and klick on one bottom. How is it possible?

Comment: try to play with the latex `input` command with something like `\input{check.Rmd}` in test.Rnw.

Comment: Do you know the functions `knit` and `knit2pdf`? I have some difficulties in understanding what you are up to, but it sounds like you just need an R script that calls these (or similar) functions.

Comment: In principle it is as follows: we have 2 files if you would compile a knitr file you would use `compilePDF`  bottom in RStudio, and for a Markdown file one  may use `KnitPDF` bottom in RStudio, BUT we want to put both together and klick on a bottom. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RStudio buttons "Compile PDF" (for RNW documents) and "Knit PDF" (for RMD documents) are convenient, but in cases like this one it is important to understand what they *do* in order to reproduce the same or similar behavior.

Summing the question up, it asks for a way to convert two files (a RMD and a RNW document) to PDF, preferably using a button like the two buttons mentioned above.

Unfortunately, (up to my knowledge) it is not possible to add any user-defined buttons to the RStudio GUI. But it is straightforward to write an R script that compiles both documents.

In the following I assume two files:

- `first.Rmd`:

  ````
  This is a RMD file.

  ```{r, echo=FALSE}
  plot(1)
  ```
  ````
- `second.Rnw`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}

  This is a RNW file.

  <<>>=
  plot(1)
  @
  \end{document}
  ```

To compile `first.Rmd` to PDF, we need the following (see [How to convert R Markdown to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025123/how-to-convert-r-markdown-to-pdf)):

```
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

knit(input = "first.Rmd")
render(input = "first.md", output_format = "pdf_document")
```

The `knit` call generates `first.md` from `first.Rmd`, execting the R code in the chunks.  `render` converts the resulting markdown file to PDF. [Note the addendum at the bottom!]

To compile `first.Rnw` to PDF, we can simply use `knit2pdf`:

```
knit2pdf("second.Rnw")
```

Copying both snippets into one R script and clicking "Source" is as close as possible to a "one-button-solution".

However, note that the snippets do something very similar to the "Compile / knit PDF" button, but it is *not identical*. The "Compile" buttons start a **new R session** while the solution above uses the **current session**.

- Before executing the snippets make sure to use the correct working directory.
- Both `knit` and `knit2pdf` by default use `envir = parent.frame()`. That means R code in chunks is executed in the *calling* enironment (see [What is the difference between `parent.frame()` and `parent.env()` in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439568/2706569)). This can be a useful feature, for example to "pass" variables to chunks, but it is important to know about it. Otherwise a document might compile just fine in one session (where certain variables exist in the calling environment) but cannot be compiled in another session (that is missing these variables). Therefore, this feature is a little bit dangerous in terms of reproducibility. As a solution, `envir = new.env(parent = as.environment(2))` could be used; see [knitr inherits variables from a user's environment, even with `envir = new.env()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257970/knitr-inherits-variables-from-a-users-environment-even-with-envir-new-env) for more details on that topic.

---

I just realized to following about `render`:

> If the input requires knitting then `knit` is called prior to `pandoc`.

(Source: `?render`)

Therefore, `knit(input = "first.Rmd"); render(input = "first.md", output_format = "pdf_document")` can be simplified to `render(input = "first.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")`. The `envir` issues of `knit` from above apply to `render` as well.

Comment: Typo above: "... To compile `first.Rnw` to PDF, we can simply use ..." should be "... To compile `second.Rnw` to PDF, we can simply use ...". Thanks for your answer by the way.